# xampp error apache shutdowns unexpectedly when adding virtual host

Tags: apache, zend-framework, configuration, xampp

I know that some services uses port 80 and one of them is IIS so i already changed iis config.
Here's my problem, when I am only using httpd.conf to start apache using port 80 it works fine. But currently while going on the steps of configuring Zend Framework 2, when I already edited httpd-vhosts.conf it doesn't work anymore. Please check if my configurations are correct because as far as I can see nothing is wrong. Also tips for troubleshooting is much appreciated.

Here's my config file

httpd.conf

```
       ...
       ServerName localhost:80
       ...
       <Directory />
              AllowOverride FileInfo
              Require all denied
       </Directory>
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
      ...
      <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2proj\public"
        ServerName zf2proj
            SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
            <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2proj\public">
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow, deny 
            Allow from all
          </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>
```

C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost   <-----should all of this must not begin with #? 
    127.0.0.1       zf2proj           because when i opened hosts it has # 
    ::1             localhost         before it. (#127.0.0.1    localhost)
```

I am using xamp v1.8.3
and Windows 7 x32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trials I found the culprit.

This is the culprit

```
    ...
        <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2proj\public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow, deny 
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
   ...
```

When I delete this part of httpd-vhosts.conf xampp's apache starts.. So now my problem is how to make it work because this configuration is needed. I ended up with this config instead..

```
  ...
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2proj\public"
    ServerName zf2proj
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
  </VirtualHost>
```

so that my zend framework 2 application will start on zf2proj/public/index.php.. still not encountering any problems so far.

If anyone has any idea what happened here and if you want to add anything to my configuration. Please feel free to answer. As of now I'm gonna mark this as the answer. If anyone has a more clear and concise answer I will gladly change it.

Thanks.